# 'int' object has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas

root = Tk()
'''create canvas as a child of root window'''
c = Canvas(root, bg = "black", height = 700, width = 1200, cursor = "pencil")

'''create line in the canvas'''
c = c.create_line(50, 50, 200, 50, 200, 150, width = 4, fill = "white")

'''create oval in the canvas'''
c.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: c.pack()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pack'

Comment: You assign the result of `create_line` to `c`. That's an int. If `c` is supposed to be your canvas object, don't set it to something else.

Comment: You really could have edited Your post and put the error there

Comment: @shuhamJ Please [edit] your post and put the error there.

Comment: I suggest You use meaningful variable names and also You can simply pack a widget right after initiating

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. This isn't a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -4):

```
c = c.create_line(50, 50, 200, 50, 200, 150, width = 4, fill = "white")
```

Ans

```
line = c.create_line(50, 50, 200, 50, 200, 150, width = 4, fill = "white")

line.pack()
```

Comment: is there even a need to asign it to a variable?

Comment: Don't use `id`, that's the name of a builtin.

Comment: You can't call `pack` on canvas items. That method only works for widgets, and canvas items aren't widgets.